# Update nested field in BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to perform what, you would think, is a trivial operation in BigQuery; I am trying to update a nested field in a BigQuery table that is the result of a 360 export.

Here is my query:

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `dataset_name`.`ga_sessions_20170705`
SET hits.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'some string'
WHERE TRUE
```

But I get this error message:

`Error: Cannot access field eventInfo on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<item STRUCT<transactionId INT64, currencyCode STRING>, isEntrance BOOL, minute INT64, ...>> at [3:10]`

How can I update this nested field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hits` is an array, so you need to use an array subquery to assign to it. It would look something like this:

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `dataset_name`.`ga_sessions_20170705`
SET hits =
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      (SELECT AS STRUCT eventInfo.* REPLACE('some string' AS eventLabel)) AS eventInfo)
    FROM UNNEST(hits)
  )
WHERE TRUE;
```

Comment: Thank you for the super fast reply @Elliot! I am getting this error when I run your query: `ARRAY subquery cannot have more than one column unless using SELECT AS STRUCT to build STRUCT values at [4:3] `. Unfortunately it is a bit cryptic to me since I'm quite new to BigQuery.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the `SELECT AS STRUCT`. Does this work now?

Comment: Hmmm, now the error says `Error: Value of type ARRAY<STRUCT<item STRUCT<transactionId INT64, currencyCode STRING>, isEntrance BOOL, minute INT64, ...>> cannot be assigned to hits, which has type ARRAY<STRUCT<item STRUCT<transactionId INT64, currencyCode STRING>, isEntrance BOOL, minute INT64, ...>> at [4:3]`

Comment: Trying again...I don't have a table to run the query against so I'm writing this off the top of my head. I think I need to use REPLACE to preserve the struct field order.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to modify a given custom dimension you can use this:

```sql
#standardSQL
UPDATE `tablename`
SET hits = 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT cd.index,
          CASE WHEN cd.index = index_number THEN 'new value'
          ELSE cd.value
          END
        FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cd
      ) AS customDimensions)
    FROM UNNEST(hits) hit
  )
WHERE TRUE
```

But it takes a while to run.

Comment: Thanks @María García Gumbao this example helped me. But mine was for hit pages searching for PII data and below was is my query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is to mask PII data in ga sessions having an email

```
UPDATE
     `<project-id>.<dataset-name>.<table-name>`
 
SET hits =
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (
    -- correcting pages here
    IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r"@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+")
    ,STRUCT(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r"@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+", "[EMAIL]")
        ,page.pagePathLevel1
        ,page.pagePathLevel2
        ,page.pagePathLevel3
        ,page.pagePathLevel4
        ,page.hostname
        ,page.pageTitle
        ,page.searchKeyword
        ,page.searchCategory
    ), page) AS page)
    
    FROM UNNEST(hits)
  ) 
WHERE ( -- only relevant sessions
  SELECT COUNT(1) > 0 
  FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE totals.visits = 1
    AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
    AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r"@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+") = true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mask PII, you have to take into account that it can be located elsewhere than in the pagePath (for example in pagePathLevel).
Beware that the structure stored in BigQuery does not respect the documentation.

Here is an example to mask email, lastname and firstname.

```sql
update 
  `<project-id>.<dataset-name>.<table-name>` 
set 
  hits = (
    SELECT 
      ARRAY(
        SELECT 
          AS STRUCT * REPLACE (
            -- correcting pages here
            IF(
              (
                TRUE = REGEXP_CONTAINS(
                  page.pagePath, r "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)"
                ) 
                OR TRUE = REGEXP_CONTAINS(
                  page.pagePath, r "lastname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&"
                ) 
                OR TRUE = REGEXP_CONTAINS(
                  page.pagePath, r "firstname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&"
                )
              ), 
              STRUCT(
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                      page.pagePath, r "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)", 
                      "[REDACTED]"
                    ), 
                    r "lastname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                    "lastname=[REDACTED]&"
                  ), 
                  r "firstname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                  "firstname=[REDACTED]&"
                ), 
                page.hostname, 
                page.pageTitle, 
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                      page.searchKeyword, r "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)", 
                      "[REDACTED]"
                    ), 
                    r "lastname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                    "lastname=[REDACTED]&"
                  ), 
                  r "firstname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                  "firstname=[REDACTED]&"
                ), 
                page.searchCategory, 
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                      page.pagePathLevel1, r "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)", 
                      "[REDACTED]"
                    ), 
                    r "lastname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                    "lastname=[REDACTED]&"
                  ), 
                  r "firstname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                  "firstname=[REDACTED]&"
                ), 
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                      page.pagePathLevel2, r "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)", 
                      "[REDACTED]"
                    ), 
                    r "lastname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                    "lastname=[REDACTED]&"
                  ), 
                  r "firstname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                  "firstname=[REDACTED]&"
                ), 
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                      page.pagePathLevel3, r "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)", 
                      "[REDACTED]"
                    ), 
                    r "lastname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                    "lastname=[REDACTED]&"
                  ), 
                  r "firstname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                  "firstname=[REDACTED]&"
                ), 
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                      page.pagePathLevel4, r "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)", 
                      "[REDACTED]"
                    ), 
                    r "lastname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                    "lastname=[REDACTED]&"
                  ), 
                  r "firstname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&", 
                  "firstname=[REDACTED]&"
                )
              ), 
              page
            ) AS page
          ) 
        from 
          UNNEST(hits)
      )
  ) 
WHERE 
  (
    -- only relevant sessions
    EXISTS(
      SELECT 
        * 
      FROM 
        UNNEST(hits) AS hits 
      WHERE 
        (
          TRUE = REGEXP_CONTAINS(
            hits.page.pagePath, r "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)"
          ) 
          OR TRUE = REGEXP_CONTAINS(
            hits.page.pagePath, r "lastname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&"
          ) 
          OR TRUE = REGEXP_CONTAINS(
            hits.page.pagePath, r "firstname=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)&"
          )
        )
    )
  );
```