# Update a nested field in BigQuery using another nested field as a condition

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to update the sourcePropertyDisplayName on a ga_sessions_ table WHERE it matches the value of another nested field. I found this answer here:

[Update nested field in BigQuery table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953369/update-nested-field-in-bigquery-table)

But this only has a very simple WHERE TRUE; whereas I only want to apply it if it matches a specified hits.eventInfo.eventCategory.

Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE `dataset_name`.`ga_sessions_20170720`
SET hits =
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      (SELECT AS STRUCT sourcePropertyInfo.* REPLACE('updated text' AS 
       sourcePropertyDisplayName)) AS sourcePropertyInfo)
    FROM UNNEST(hits)
  )
WHERE ARRAY(
SELECT AS STRUCT eventInfo.eventCategory
FROM UNNEST(hits)
) LIKE '%SEARCH%'
```

But I'm currently getting following error:

```
Error: No matching signature for operator LIKE for argument types: 
ARRAY<STRUCT<eventCategory STRING>>, STRING. Supported signatures: STRING 
LIKE STRING; BYTES LIKE BYTES at [8:7]
```

How can I update one nested field by using the value of another in a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE clause should be like below

```sql
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) AS h 
  WHERE h.eventInfo.eventCategory LIKE '%SEARCH%'
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I have changed the query to:

    `UPDATE dataset_name.ga_sessions_20170720
    SET hits =
      ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
          (SELECT AS STRUCT sourcePropertyInfo.* REPLACE('updated 
    text' AS sourcePropertyDisplayName)) AS sourcePropertyInfo)
        FROM UNNEST(hits)
      )
    WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) AS h 
      WHERE h.eventInfo.eventCategory LIKE '%SEARCH%'
    )`

And I now get:
    `Error: Resources exceeded during query execution.`

With 0 rows successfully updated. Can I do anything about this?

Comment: i would recommend first to test if the WHERE clause works (as this was the focus of your question) - to do so you can just run select count(1) from \`dataset_name.ga_sessions_20170720\`
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) AS h WHERE h.eventInfo.eventCategory LIKE '%SEARCH%' ) - so at least you will know that WHERE works or maybe is a cause for `Resources exceeded` error. if it works  - to address error you should post another question I think :o)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Running your query works, so I will investigate the resources issue and post a separate issue if necessary.