# Updating nested array in BigQuery based on value in another column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a problem with BigQuery syntax that I'm a bit stuck on. I have an entry in a table that has multiple key value pairs as an array and I would like to update only a single specific string in the values when the key is a certain value.

Here is the entry

```
[
  {
    "event_params": [
      {
        "key": "programType",
        "value": {
          "string_value": "custom",
          "int_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "firebase_event_origin",
        "value": {
          "string_value": "app",
          "int_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "firebase_screen_id",
        "value": {
          "string_value": null,
          "int_value": "5",
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "programName",
        "value": {
          "string_value": "overwrite_me",
          "int_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I would like to keep everything the same except when "key" = "programName" I want to overwrite the string_value "overwrite_me" with the new string "anonymous". In general, the string_value is some arbitrary string and I just want it overwritten with the same value.

Based on a few answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907954/google-bigquery-updating-a-nested-repeated-field) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241798/update-a-nested-field-in-bigquery-using-another-nested-field-as-a-condition?noredirect=1&lq=1) I have tried the following query (and various permutations of it)

```
SET
event_params = ARRAY(
   SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
     CASE WHEN event_param.key = 'programName' THEN
      ((SELECT AS STRUCT value.* REPLACE('anonymous' AS string_value)) AS value)
    END
  ) 
  FROM UNNEST(event_params) as event_param 
)
```

but BigQuqery always gives me syntax errors, specifically "Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AS at [9:73]". I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong and I'm quite puzzled.

Comment: Have you declared your array before using the SET method? Also, which errors are you getting?

Comment: Yes all the arrays are declared. I excluded the code that gets all the entries in the table. The errors are a mix between syntax errors such as "Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AS" which I don't quite understand why the syntax is wrong and other times (not with the above code) I get the "Error: Cannot access field name on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT.. . ".

Comment: I am investigating it and I will get back to you.

Comment: It's been puzzling me for a few days. One solution my colleagues and I came up with was to reconstruct the structure manually, and it works, but it messes up the column names which isn't helpful. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176795/bigquery-update-nested-array-field?rq=1) for a very similarly related question would work, except here we have key-value pairs which isn't quite what this solution gives and I just couldn't make it work with a  join.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce it with a public data set with a similar struct. That is why I am taking a little longer to try to figure it out. I saw the example you wrote and it is indeed a slightly different, I am still researching about it and I will let you know.

Comment: I was able to reproduce a similar case, I hope it might help you. I used a public data set and saved in a local dataset thus I could _UPDATE the dataset with the values I wanted. The query is as follows: UPDATE ` firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_20181003 `
SET event_params = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE ( 'TEST' AS key)
  FROM UNNEST (event_params)
)
WHERE event_params.key = 'value'_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

See corrected version of very yours code

```
SET
event_params = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
    CASE WHEN event_param.key = 'programName' THEN
      (SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE('anonymous' AS string_value) FROM UNNEST([value]))
    ELSE value
   END AS value
  ) 
  FROM UNNEST(event_params) AS event_param 
)
```

Also, note - you can remove reference to `event_param` as in below example

```
SET
event_params = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
    CASE WHEN key = 'programName' THEN
      (SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE('anonymous' AS string_value) FROM UNNEST([value]))
    ELSE value
   END AS value
  ) 
  FROM UNNEST(event_params)  
)
```

Comment: Ah perfect! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.