# Updating nested fields in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got a bigquery table with a nested field 'user_properties', which containts key and a struct of several values (string_value, int_value etc). I need to update those cells, where key = test and value - string value.

For now i've got the following code:

```
  UPDATE `table` 
  SET user_properties =
    ARRAY(

      SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
        (SELECT AS STRUCT value.* REPLACE('zzzzzzz' AS string_value)  FROM UNNEST(user_properties) WHERE key = 'test' ) AS value )
      FROM UNNEST(user_properties) 
    )

    WHERE TRUE
```

It updates all the cells for string_value, not only 'test'.
How can i update only specific cell?

Comment: Hello, that question is quite similar to the one asked here in this StackOverflow question [1]. I think Mikhail Berlyant's answer might help you answer your question as well.
[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822154/updating-nested-array-in-bigquery-based-on-value-in-another-column

Comment: Hi, thanks! Yes, the moderators have closed this thread and gave me the link too :)