BigQuery MERGE rows UPDATE field in STRUCT if the values in the nested field match each other
BigQuery using GoogleSQL.
Trying to MERGE data from staging table into existing table. I have a STRUCT of counts that need to be updated but I can't figure out how to get into the STRUCT to first apply a condition and then update the values. EDIT: I was trying for something like this Updating nested array in BigQuery based on value in another column My query below gives the error: Cannot access field type on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<type STRING, count INT64, amount INT64>> at [25:43].
MERGE
  caches.table1 old
USING
  (
  SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(type,
        count,
        amount)) AS normalized_counts
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      type,
      COUNT(*) AS count,
      SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
      production.table2
    GROUP BY
      id,
      type)
  GROUP BY
    id) staging
ON
  old.id = staging.id
  WHEN MATCHED AND (old.normalized_counts.type = staging.normalized_counts.type) THEN UPDATE SET normalized_counts.count = old.normalized_counts.count + staging.normalized_counts.count, normalized_counts.amount = old.normalized_counts.amount + staging.normalized_counts.amount
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN
INSERT
  (id,
    field2,
    normalized_counts,
    field3,
    field4,
    field5)
VALUES
  (id, NULL, normalized_counts, NULL, NULL, NULL)

I've tried UNNEST(), which works, but then I don't know how to put it back into its original schema inside the UPDATE part. So right now I have 3 steps:
Step 1: Create a table with the unnested normalized_counts field from the existing table.
Step 2: Merge rows from staging into the existing table.
Step 3: Aggregate into normalized_counts STRUCT again, and join to rest of existing table, overwrite existing table with this.
Is it possible to get them all into one MERGE query? My best attempt was the query above.
Edit: Adding screenshots to show table schema, inputs and expected result.
Schema of existing and staging table:

existing table input:

staging table input:

expected result (the updated existing table should look like this):


While it is very possible someone can assist based on the rich description you have already given, what would encourage me to assist is some illustrative data and a description of what a desired result set would look like.   Maybe consider describing a simplified puzzle that illustrates a minimal story (assuming that there is superflous parts in the above SQL that correspond to a business solution rather than are necessary to describe the core of the logical puzzle).

I've added screenshots of schema, both input tables, and desired result.

First create a function that handles array merging logic:
create temp function merge_normalized_counts(
  enc array<struct<type string, count int64, amount int64>>, -- existing normalized counts
  snc array<struct<type string, count int64, amount int64>> -- staging normalized counts
) as
((
  select 
    array_agg(struct(
      type, 
      coalesce(e.count, 0) + coalesce(s.count, 0) as count,
      coalesce(e.amount, 0) + coalesce(s.amount, 0) as amount
    ))
  from (select * from unnest(enc)) as e
  full join (select * from unnest(snc)) as s
    using(type)
)); 

select merge_normalized_counts(
  [
    struct("delivery" as type, 3 as count, 1200 as amount),
    struct("xx" as type, 3 as count, 1200 as amount)
  ],
  [
    struct("delivery" as type, 1 as count, 0 as amount),
    struct("yy" as type, 1 as count, 0 as amount)
  ]
) as test_output

Here, we can validate if our merge logic works well with different use cases as well. Output for my test input:

Then we can use it in our merge statement:
create temp table existing as
select 
  "12345abcd" as id,
  [
    struct("delivery" as type, 3 as count, 1200 as amount),
    struct("xx" as type, 3 as count, 1200 as amount)
  ] as normalized_counts
;

create temp table staging as
select 
  "12345abcd" as id,
  [
    struct("delivery" as type, 1 as count, 0 as amount),
    struct("yy" as type, 1 as count, 0 as amount)
  ] as normalized_counts
;

create temp function merge_normalized_counts(
  enc array<struct<type string, count int64, amount int64>>, -- existing normalized counts
  snc array<struct<type string, count int64, amount int64>> -- staging normalized counts
) as
((
  select 
    array_agg(struct(
      type, 
      coalesce(e.count, 0) + coalesce(s.count, 0) as count,
      coalesce(e.amount, 0) + coalesce(s.amount, 0) as amount
    ))
  from (select * from unnest(enc)) as e
  full join (select * from unnest(snc)) as s
    using(type)
)); 

merge existing as e
using staging as s
  on e.id = s.id
when not matched then insert (id, normalized_counts) values (id, normalized_counts)
when matched then
  UPDATE SET normalized_counts = merge_normalized_counts(e.normalized_counts, s.normalized_counts)
;

select *
from existing


Unfortunately BigQuery returns an error, so it looks like it's not possible.

Hey, thanks for the effort! I've been turning it all sort of ways. I struggled with the same error, I didn't use a function, just typed it all into the subquery and got the same error.

No worries, by the way, I think it's not a good pattern to update the existing table. This way, your tables won't be idempotent. Instead, I'd recommend recreating the table every time. If you think it's too big, you can use aggregated monthly, yearly, etc tables to make it faster.

Thanks! What I was trying to do was along the lines of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822154/updating-nested-array-in-bigquery-based-on-value-in-another-column, but can't get it to work needing info from nested fields in both existing and staging table.
