# How to update a field in a nested array in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to update a table that has STRUCT(a few fields, ARRAY(STRUCT)).
The field that I need to update is inside the array and I am having trouble with making it work.

Here is the layout of the the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE mydatset.orders (
order_id  string,
order_time timestamp,
trans  STRUCT <
    id      string,
    amount      INT64,
    accounts      ARRAY<STRUCT <
          role      STRING ,
          account_id        STRING,
          region          STRING,
          amount      INT64> > >
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE mydatset.relocations (
    account_id    string,
    region      string
)
```

Trying to update the region of any account in the array accounts if that account exists in the relocations table:

```
update mydataset.orders a
set trans = (SELECT AS STRUCT   trans.* REPLACE(ARRAY(SELECT STRUCT<role STRING, account_id STRING, region STRING, amount INT64>
                          (cp.role,  cp.account_id,
                           case when cp.account_id = ll.account_id then ll.region else cp.region end ,
                           cp.amount
                          )
                    ) as accounts )
    from unnest(trans.accounts) cp
    left join unnest(relocs.chgs) ll
    on cp.account_id = ll.account_id
    )
from (select array_agg(struct (account_id, region) ) chgs
      from`mydataset.relocations`
      ) relocs
where true
```

The syntax works, but the sql doesn't perform the expected update. The account's region in the orders table is not changed after running the above update!

(I have seen [BigQuery UPDATE nested array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176795/bigquery-update-nested-array-field) and this case is slightly different. The array is inside a struct and itself is an array of struct)

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `project.dataset.orders`
SET trans = (SELECT AS STRUCT trans.* REPLACE(
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT x.* REPLACE(IFNULL(y.region, x.region) AS region)
    FROM UNNEST(trans.accounts) x
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(relocations) y
    USING(account_id)
  ) AS accounts))
FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t) relocations FROM `project.dataset.relocations` t)
WHERE TRUE
```

It is tested with below dummy data

initial dummy data that looks like below

```
[
  {
    "order_id": "order_id1",
    "order_time": "2019-06-28 01:05:16.346854 UTC",
    "trans": {
      "id": "id1",
      "amount": "1",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "role": "role1",
          "account_id": "account_id1",
          "region": "region1",
          "amount": "11"
        },
        {
          "role": "role2",
          "account_id": "account_id2",
          "region": "region2",
          "amount": "12"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "order_id": "order_id2",
    "order_time": "2019-06-28 01:05:16.346854 UTC",
    "trans": {
      "id": "id2",
      "amount": "1",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "role": "role3",
          "account_id": "account_id1",
          "region": "region4",
          "amount": "13"
        },
        {
          "role": "role4",
          "account_id": "account_id3",
          "region": "region3",
          "amount": "14"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

after applying below adjustments

```
[
  {
    "account_id": "account_id1",
    "region": "regionA"
  },
  {
    "account_id": "account_id2",
    "region": "regionB"
  }
]
```

result is

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "amount": "1",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "role": "role1",
        "account_id": "account_id1",
        "region": "regionA",
        "amount": "11"
      },
      {
        "role": "role2",
        "account_id": "account_id2",
        "region": "regionB",
        "amount": "12"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "amount": "1",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "role": "role3",
        "account_id": "account_id1",
        "region": "regionA",
        "amount": "13"
      },
      {
        "role": "role4",
        "account_id": "account_id3",
        "region": "region3",
        "amount": "14"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Strange, I get the following error when I try you query as is (only replacing the dataset name):
Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.
(I think that was why originally I used array_agg for the data from the relocations table.)

Comment: argh. I was mostly focusing on adjusting your query assuming that it is correct at a core. let me check this again - will get back shortly

Comment: @FZF - see updated answer  - it is tested now - so should definitely work for you :o)