# Update ARRAY IN ARRAY BigQuery (GA4 Data)

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, sql-update

I want to update a value in array with a value in another table.

table1:

| event_params.key | event_params.value.string_value |
| --- | --- |
| country | US |

table2:

| country | new_country |
| --- | --- |
| US | NL |

I try

```
UPDATE table1

SET event_params = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE ( new_country AS value.string_value ) FROM UNNEST(event_params) 
WHERE key = "country")

FROM(SELECT country, new_country FROM table2)

WHERE 
(SELECT value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'country') = t2.country
```

It doesnt work.. The problem is the value.string_value because is also an array.

The final table should look like
table1:

| event_params.key | event_params.value.string_value |
| --- | --- |
| country | NL |

Now I want to update table1 with table2 to udate the country from US to NL in table1.

How can I take the array in array?

Answer (score 0):

I also saw this code:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.your_table` t
SET hits = 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT product.* REPLACE(
          CASE WHEN map.raw_name = product.productCategory THEN category 
            ELSE productCategoryAttribute END AS productCategoryAttribute)
        FROM UNNEST(product) product
        LEFT JOIN UNNEST(agg_map.map) map 
        ON map.raw_name = product.productCategory
      ) AS product)
    FROM UNNEST(hits) hit
  ) 
FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(row) map FROM `project.dataset.map` row) agg_map 
WHERE TRUE
```

[BigQuery UPDATE nested array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176795/bigquery-update-nested-array-field)
But I cant implement it.