# Update sql request with nestjs & bigquery

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, google-bigquery, nestjs

First of all, I know that you shouldn't update in bigquery with an SQL query, but for my needs, I have to go through that.

Then the problem I have is that everything works correctly (the update of the other fields) but not the nested object table field

See bigquery schema:

```json
[
  {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "REQUIRED"
  },
  {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "REQUIRED"
  },
  {
      "name": "type",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "REQUIRED"
  },
  {
      "name": "descriptions",
      "type": "RECORD",
      "mode": "REPEATED",
      "description": "Descriptions in specific languages",
      "fields": [
          {
              "name":"description",
              "type":"RECORD",
              "mode":"REQUIRED",
              "description":"The description item",
              "fields":[
                  {
                      "name":"language",
                      "type":"STRING",
                      "mode":"REQUIRED",
                      "description":"The language of the description"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "text",
                      "type": "STRING",
                      "mode": "REQUIRED",
                      "description": "The text of the description"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
]
```

I'm using Nestjs (npm package @google-cloud/bigquery) and bigquery in the query column.

The query (or rather one of the queries, I tried several, in vain):

```sql
UPDATE
  myDataset.myTable
SET
  JSON_SET( descriptions, '$[0].description.language', 'es', '$[0].description.text', 'test-es' ),
  JSON_SET( descriptions, '$[1].description.language', 'jp', '$[1].description.text', 'test-jp' ),
  id = '1',
  name = 'TEST',
  type = 'LANG',
  descriptions = JSON_ARRAY([{"description":{"language":"es","text":"test-es"}},{"description":{"language":"jp","text":"test-jp"}}])
WHERE
  id = '1'
```

I tried to make several queries, including in my code or in Bigquery directly, but I get several errors, such as this query:

```
Syntax error: Expected "." or "=" or "[" but got "(" at [4:11]
```

I'm trying to update my data in bigquery but I only get errors in my nested object array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update nested field in BigQuery table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953369/update-nested-field-in-bigquery-table)

Comment: Hello no, it doesn't help me and it is not adapted to my needs and my request (which will depend on the users who can add one or more languages, so I build the request in js)